# Oracle: Prevent\Mitigate Ora-01652 when runnig large Insert/Select statement

Tags: oracle, bigdata, business-intelligence, query-performance

The error ORA-01652 is hauting for some time. I've spoke with my DBA team and they increased the temp tablespace twice and today it has 120 GB. Even then, I'm still getting the ORA-01652, but with less frequency instead.

Whenever I try to create an aggregate view from a billionary row table, I'll certanlly get the ORA-01652 for intervals greater than a month. For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_AGG_BY_MIN AS
SELECT 
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') DATETIME
    , COUNT(*) COUNTVALUE
FROM BIG_TABLE
WHERE DATETIME >= DATE '2019-01-01'
  AND DATETIME <  DATE '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI');
```

Thus, in order to prevent the problem with the temp tablespace, I have to break the above query in something like:

```
-- 2019-JAN
CREATE TABLE TEMP_AGG_BY_MIN AS
SELECT 
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') DATETIME
    , COUNT(*) COUNTVALUE
FROM BIG_TABLE
WHERE DATETIME >= DATE '2019-01-01'
  AND DATETIME <  DATE '2019-02-01'
GROUP BY
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI');

-- 2019-FEV
INSERT INTO TEMP_AGG_BY_MIN 
SELECT 
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') DATETIME
    , COUNT(*) COUNTVALUE
FROM BIG_TABLE
WHERE DATETIME >= DATE '2019-02-01'
  AND DATETIME <  DATE '2019-03-01'
GROUP BY
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI');

COMMMIT;

-- 2019-MAR
INSERT INTO TEMP_AGG_BY_MIN 
SELECT 
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') DATETIME
    , COUNT(*) COUNTVALUE
FROM BIG_TABLE
WHERE DATETIME >= DATE '2019-03-01'
  AND DATETIME <  DATE '2019-04-01'
GROUP BY
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATETIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI');

COMMMIT;

...
-- 2019-other months till complete the year
```

Although that works, it increases the chance of error and consumes me time to keep\guarantee that I will not overlap data among months and writting 'unecessary queries'.

Said that, I would like to know 1) how do you folks deals with that situation and 2) if this problem is something that will probably occur with any other databases as well.

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE 1

- Size of TEMP_AGG_BY_MIN:     5 GB (~ 140 million rows)
- Size of   BIG_TABLE:       470 GB (~ 6 billion rows) partitioned by months
- How long does the CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (CTAS) take? For a month, it
  takes ~ 10 minutes
- Do you know if your the temporary tablespace is used a lot by other CTAS 
  during this timeframe ? Probably not, because it's a pretty recent created 
  database
- Oracle version: 12c Enterprise

UPDATE 2

Below is the real execution plan, as @pifor suggested. I couldn't get the `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET` til the moment.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                        | Name             | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | CREATE TABLE STATEMENT           |                  |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |      0 |       |       |          |
|   1 |  LOAD AS SELECT                  | TEMP_AGG_BY_MIN  |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |      0 |   256K|   256K|          |
|   2 |   OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING |                  |      1 |    399M|      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |      0 |   256K|   256K|          |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY                 |                  |      1 |    399M|      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |      0 |    66M|    11M|          |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER        |                  |      1 |    399M|    378M|00:01:02.32 |    3421K|   3421K|   195M|    17M|  218M (0)|
|   5 |      TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL   | SMALL_TABLE      |      1 |   3319K|   3319K|00:00:00.11 |   16477 |  16457 |  1025K|  1025K| 6170K (0)|
|   6 |      PARTITION RANGE SINGLE      |                  |      1 |    399M|    378M|00:00:16.30 |    3404K|   3404K|       |       |          |
|*  7 |       TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL  | BIG_TABLE        |      1 |    399M|    378M|00:00:15.87 |    3404K|   3404K|  1025K|  1025K| 6170K (0)|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   4 - access("L"."ID"="M"."ID")
   7 - storage(("M"."DATETIME">=TIMESTAMP' 2019-11-01 00:00:00' AND "M"."DATETIME"<TIMESTAMP' 2019-12-01 00:00:00'))
        filter(("M"."DATETIME">=TIMESTAMP' 2019-11-01 00:00:00' AND "M"."DATETIME"<TIMESTAMP' 2019-12-01 00:00:00'))
```

Comment: What is the size of TEMP_AGG_BY_MIN in MB/GB ? What is the size of BIG_TABLE in MB/GB ? Is BIG_TABLE partionned ? How long does the CREATE TABLE AS SELECT (CTAS) take ? Do you know if your the temporary tablespace is used a lot by other CTAS during this timeframe ? Ideally we should have an execution plan with DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR for the CTAS and a AWR/Statspack report. What is Oracle version ? Is it Standard Edition or Entreprise Edition ?

Comment: I suspect the CTAS needs a lot of temporary space. Could you try to run the CTAS with the hint `/*+ GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS */` and just after to retrieve the real execution plan with : `SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.display_cursor(format=>'ALLSTATS LAST'));` . See https://sqlmaria.com/2017/08/08/using-dbms_xplan-display_cursor-to-examine-execution-plans/ for a full example. What is the value of parameter `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET` ?